# Как указать тип обьекта который передали в компонент

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, react-router, react-hook

Когда, принимаю объкт в другой компонент, хочу указать тип ArrayTS, но так не получается, можно только указать тип any, но тогда все свойства интерфейса теряются

```
     interface ArrayTS {
    readonly id: string; // только для чтения
    color?: string;     // не обяз пааметр
    size: {
      width: number;
      heidth: number;
    };
    dynamicVariable: any;
    interfaceArray: Array<number>;
    setValue(value: number): number;
  }
```

сам объект

```
  const objectTS: ArrayTS = {
        id: "1234",
        size: {
          width: 20,
          heidth: 30,
        },
        color: "fff",
        dynamicVariable: "Любой тип",
        interfaceArray: [1, 2, 3],
        setValue(value: number): number {
        return value;
        }
      };


     {/*передача обьекта */}
      <Object objectTS={objectTS}/>
```

принимаю обьект

```
 interface Propsinterface {
        objectTS: ArrayTS,
        
    }
    
    const Object: React.FC<Propsinterface> = ({objectTS}) => {
```

Comment: Не совсем понятно что не получается, с интерфейсом все нормально, не хватает описания ошибки, возможно ошибка в другом, например объект пуст или что-то еще

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Возможно Вы просто не экспортируете интерфейс?

```
export interface ArrayTS {
  readonly id: string;
  color?: string;
  size: {
    width: number;
    heidth: number;
  };
  dynamicVariable: any;
  interfaceArray: Array<number>;
  setValue(value: number): number;
}
```

И импортируйте его

```
import {ArrayTS} from "./YourComponent";
interface Propsinterface {
  objectTS: ArrayTS,
}
    
const Object: React.FC<Propsinterface> = ({objectTS}) => {
```